# how to compare two date columns using procedure and if these dates are equal then insert all the fields of 2nd table into first table

Tags: oracle

i have a table EMP and having a field Date_of_joining and i have a another table INTERN having a attribute Date_of_joining. Compare Date_of_joining if both are equal then copy all the field's values of INTERN table into EMP.
Using Procedure in ORACLE.

same type of columns both the table's have.

please help me guys.

Answer (score 0):

Use merge dml statement.
Just look into ora documentation
[Click](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm)